# servlet multiple exec commands

Tags: java, python, servlets, terminal

I am writing a servlet to run terminal commands, I have to run three commands one after the another on the same terminal.
When I use exec as shown below I am able to get the result for the single command,

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
process proc = rt.exec("zsh");
```

but when I attempt to run,

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec("zsh", "source ./myenv/bin/activate", "python runner.py");
```

it shows a warning (doesn't execute) as follows,

```
The method exec(String, String[], File) in the type Runtime is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String).
```

I've also tried running three differed exec commands but they do not happen in the same sequence and on the same terminal, what should I do to make the above three commands to run on the same terminal sequentially and give me the output after the third command?

The three commands I intent to run are,
1. zsh
2. source ./myenv/bin/activate
3. python runner.py
all the three must be executed one after the other in the same sequence.

Comment: Can you create a script containing the three commands and execute it?

Comment: it is not executable, it gives the above described warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exec takes a String[] not a varargs list so you need to run:

```
Process proc = rt.exec(new String[] {"zsh", "source ./myenv/bin/activate", 
    "python runner.py"}, null, new File("parentdirectoryofmyenv"));
```

As shown you also need to include the working directory for the process or it won't be able to find "./myenv".

EDIT:

Simplifying this further. I am assuming that "source ./myenv/bin/activate" is setting the environment for the process. This can be done as follows:

```
Process proc = rt.exec(
     new String[] {"python", "runner.py"}, 
     new String[] {"ENV1=VAL1", "ENV2=VAL2"}, 
     new File("parentdirectoryofrunnerpy"));
```

Comment: still getting the error, "zsh: can't open input file: source ./myenv/bin/activate"..The commands seems to work fine when I've executed them from the terminal.

Comment: You are probably running it in the wrong working directory. I've updated the answer to show how to add the working dir.

Comment: Nah! I just executed pwd from my servlet to confirm it.

Comment: I've tried the new EDIT's too, still the same error persists.

Comment: What is the error you get now. You can't have the same error if you've removed the use of ./myenv/bin/activate

Comment: I can't remove ./myenv/bin/activate...I need for activating my python virtualenv. I've tried this one 

Process proc = rt.exec(new String[] {"zsh", "source ./myenv/bin/activate", 
    "python runner.py"}, null, new File("parentdirectoryofmyenv"));

Comment: can you try putting the full path the activate script in instead of ./myenv/bin/activate.

Comment: Yep, Just tried that too. Still couldn't figure out the reason.